# GetLocalWorkspaceInfo always get null

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015

my problem is really similar to [TFS API: GetLocalWorkspaceInfo always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956307/tfs-api-getlocalworkspaceinfo-always-returns-null), except I am using visual studio 2015, so those answers don't really work for me. And I tried GetAllLocalWorkspaceInfo, it returns a null as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code snippet you referred in VS 2015 and got a successful result. Make sure you have reference the dlls in VS 2015: `c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\T‌​eam Explorer`

And in the code snippet, you need to use `Console.WriteLine` to output the workspace information that you want:

```
private static Workspace FindWorkspaceByPath(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs, string workspacePath)
        {

            VersionControlServer versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            WorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(workspacePath);

            if (workspaceInfo != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(workspaceInfo.Computer);
                Console.WriteLine(workspaceInfo.DisplayName);
                return versionControl.GetWorkspace(workspaceInfo);
            }

            //No Workspace found using method 1, try to query all workspaces the user has on this machine.
            Workspace[] workspaces = versionControl.QueryWorkspaces(null, Environment.UserName, Environment.MachineName);
            foreach (Workspace w in workspaces)
            {
                foreach (WorkingFolder f in w.Folders)
                {
                    if (f.LocalItem.Equals(workspacePath))
                    {
                        return w;
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new Exception(String.Format("TFS Workspace cannot be determined for {0}.", workspacePath));
        }
```

Comment: But how do you build your tfs object? And how can one determine the workspacePath?

Answer (score -2):

I found out this issue is because of package version, so if you have this issue, please check the version of your package matches the version of your visual studio